# SMTP outbound emails stuck in Queue folder : Windows XP SP3, IIS 5.1

Tags: email, windows-xp, smtp, iis-5

I am using a PHP script for sending emails by IIS 5.1 SMTP.
The emails, go to outbound folder. really path is `C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue`.
after a seconds, it start to send emails properly, but after sending 5 or 6 emails, it stops to send the other ones. SMTP service is still start and it seems there is no problem to SMTP service.
but,If i restart the service, it sends 1 or 2 other emails and then, it stops again.
I mean sending emails stop but service is start.
by the way, emails are stucked in `Queue` folder.
Also i checked `Badmail` folder. it is empty

Thanks

Comment: Is there more text following "450 service permits 100000 unverifyable sending IPs"? For example, "service permits 100000 unverifyable sending IPs - yourdomain.com is not 1.2.3.4"?

Answer (score 0):

are all the emails to the same network? I have seen behaviour like this when the recipient server bans you, yahoo's (xtra) used to do it sometimes to our server in particular. You can check the logs in event viewer for something from the smtp server, you'll find a message from the other server saying something to the effect that you have been temporarily banned, possibly with more detail about why. Trying to connect via telnet also gives you the same message.

When this happens windows will try and send them again later. Restarting the server starts to try sending again and if the ban condition has been lifted messages will flow for a while again until you are rebanned.

Comment: i checked event viewer. there are some warnings about SMTP. for example:
`Message delivery to the remote domain 'att.net' failed.  The error message is 'An SMTP protocol error occurred.
'. The SMTP verb which caused the error is 'MAIL'.  The response from the remote server is '450 service permits 100000 unverifyable sending IPs`
or this one:

`Message delivery to the remote domain 'att.net' failed.  The error message is 'An SMTP protocol error occurred.
'. The SMTP verb which caused the error is 'MAIL'.The response from the remote server is '450 service permits 100000 unverifyable sending IPs`